# Перейти к следующему фото в альбоме вконтакте с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нашел селектор, который отвечает за переход к следующему фото из альбома вконтакте: `#pv_nav_btn_right` хотел перейти таким образом:

```
document.getElementById("pv_nav_btn_right").click()
```

Но не реагирует. Как можно выполнить данную задачу?

*Делаю через консоль google chrome.*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, вообще-то, там не просто click, а mousedown. Используйте $('#pv_nav_btn_left').onmousedown(); и $('#pv_nav_btn_right').onmousedown();